# Move code from main to an existing branch

Tags: git, branch

I have code `myscript.py` that is on `main` and I am trying to move it to an existing branch `branchA`.

```
% git branch
  branchA
* main
```

`myscript.py` is on `main`, how can I move it to `branchA` so that it no longer appears on `main`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code—or more precisely, *files*—reside(s) in *commits*.

Branches—or more precisely, branch *names*—*select* commits.  Even more precisely, a branch name holds the raw hash ID of *one particular commit*.  All other commits that are in the branch, are in the branch because of that particular commit.

No commit, once made, can ever be changed.  But the raw hash ID stored in a *branch name* can *always* be changed.  In fact, that's the whole point of branch names: to store an ever-changing hash ID.

As we make *new* commits, Git:

- packages up a new source snapshot;
- adds some *metadata*, or information about the new commit we're making right now;
- writes all of this out as a commit, which gains a new, unique hash ID; and
- writes the *hash ID* of the *new* commit into the *branch name*.

Because one piece of the metadata that Git adds in the second step is the hash ID of the *current* commit, as stored in the branch name at the time we run `git commit`, this makes the *new* commit link back to what used to be the current commit.  If we start out with a chain of commits with hash IDs, where we represent the raw hash IDs with single uppercase letters to maintain our personal sanity, we might have something like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here `H` stands for the hash ID of the *current* (and so far, last!) commit.  The branch name `main` stores this raw hash ID, so the name `main` *points to* commit `H`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- main
```

Meanwhile the metadata stored *in* commit `H` contains the raw hash ID of earlier commit `G`, so we say that `H` points to `G`.  That's the arrow coming out of `H`.  Commit `G`, of course, is a commit, so it has a stored hash ID, which in this case points to still-earlier commit `F`, and so on.

Now, again, *no existing commit can ever change*.  Our normal use of Git is to *add new commits*, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, somebranch
```

Note how we have two names—`main` and `somebranch`—that *both point to commit `H`.

We run `git checkout main` or `git switch main`, edit code, run `git add`, and run `git commit`.  Git packages up a new snapshot and makes a new commit that we'll call `I`.  Because we have `main` checked out, Git writes the new hash ID into the name `main`.  To remember which one we have checked out, let's attach the name `HEAD` to `main`, and draw in the new commit:

```
...--G--H   <-- somebranch
         \
          I   <-- main (HEAD)
```

Note how `main` *moved*, while `somebranch` didn't.  If we now `git checkout somebranch` or `git switch somebranch`, we get:

```
...--G--H   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
         \
          I   <-- main
```

The *files* from commit `I` *vanish*, and instead, we have the files from commit `H`.  Git has removed those that go with commit `I`—they're safely stored in the `I` snapshot—and replaced them with the files from `H`.

We can now address one way to answer your question:

> `myscript.py` is on `main`, how can I move it to `branchA` so that it no longer appears on `main`?

We should draw what you have.  I'm not sure what commit your `branchA` selects, nor what commit your `main` selects, so I have to guess: your own drawing would be better, or you could run `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` or any of the other fancy commands from [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452).  But let's say we have:

```
       G--H   <-- branchA
      /
...--F
      \
       I   <-- main (HEAD)
```

Let's further assume that all files are committed (because if not, you have more options).

You can simply run:

```
git rm myscript.py
git commit
```

to make a *new* commit on `main` that *lacks* the file:

```
       G--H   <-- branchA
      /
...--F
      \
       I--J   <-- main (HEAD)
```

Commit `J` no longer has the file.  Now you can `git switch branchA` to switch to your existing branch `branchA` and commit `H`:

```
       G--H   <-- branchA (HEAD)
      /
...--F
      \
       I--J   <-- main
```

You now see all the files from commit `H`, which of course means you *don't* see `myscript.py`.  But we know it's saved permanently in commit `I`, so we need to tell Git: *go get this one saved file from this existing commit*.

There are multiple commands to do this; the one I generally recommend is `git restore`, with the `--source` and `-SW` options:

```
git restore --source main~1 -SW -- myscript.py
```

which is a bit longwinded, and does the same thing as the older command:

```
git checkout main~1 -- myscript.py
```

That is, it uses the name `main` with the suffix `~1` to find commit `J` first (`main`), then step back once (`~1`) to commit `I`.  Then it finds the file named `myscript.py` that is *in* that commit and copies that file to two places:

- `-W` copies the file to your *working tree*, where you can see and edit it.
- `-S` copies the file to Git's *staging area*, where it is now ready to be committed.

The `git checkout` command doesn't have `-S` and `-W` flags: it just always copies to both places.

Now that you have this file *and* it's already `git add`-ed, you simply need to run `git commit` to make a new commit that will update the current (`HEAD`) branch name:

```
       G--H--K   <-- branchA (HEAD)
      /
...--F
      \
       I--J   <-- main
```

Commit `K` is exactly like existing commit `H` except that it has this one new file added.

Note that these commits, in these branches, *are* the history.  Commits up through commit `F` are *in both branches*.  The way that Git finds these commits is to use the branch names to find the *last* commit and then work backwards.

#### There are more options

If you *haven't* committed the file yet, it is currently only in your working tree and maybe also in Git's staging area.  See [joshmeranda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69096154/1256452), but note that `git switch -c` tries to create a *new* branch; you want `git switch`, which uses the *existing branch*.

Here, we can count on the fact that the commit identified by the name `branchA` *does not* have a file named `myscript.py` in it.  This gets extremely complicated in practice, though for this case it's simple.  For all the gory details, see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).

All of the above is about *adding more commits*.  In some cases, we have some commits and we *don't like them* for some reason.  In such cases, we can—within limits—tell Git to *stop using these commits*.

Consider the case where we have:

```
       G--H   <-- branchA
      /
...--F
      \
       I   <-- main (HEAD)
```

and we decide that we don't *like* commit `I`.  What we do is leave it alone initially, and use it to copy the file `myscript.py` to a new commit we add to `branchA`:

```
       G--H--J   <-- branchA (HEAD)
      /
...--F
      \
       I   <-- main
```

using the same `git restore` technique (though this time we use `--source main`, not `--source main~1`, since we did not make a new commit *on* `main`).

Then, though, we `git switch` back to `main` and run:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

or:

```
git reset --hard main~1
```

The `~1` suffix does the same thing as before: find the commit, then step back one hop.  This locates commit `F`.  We could run `git log` and use the mouse to cut and paste the raw hash ID of commit `F`:

```
git reset --hard <hash>
```

here.  Next, `git reset`:

- moves the *branch name* to the commit we selected;
- resets Git's index / staging-area; and
- makes your working tree match (due to the `--hard`).

This leaves us with:

```
       G--H--J   <-- branchA
      /
...--F   <-- main (HEAD)
      \
       I   ???
```

Note how there is no longer any *name* by which to *find* commit `I`.  If you've memorized its hash ID, or written it down on paper, or something, you can still find it that way.  Git provides other ways to get it back, for at least 30 days by default, as well.  But mostly it *seems* to be gone, as if it never existed.

So now it looks like the *last* commit on `main` is commit `F`, not commit `I`.  As long as nobody else has commit `I`—you never sent it to some other Git repository—it's safe to "get rid of" a commit like this.  If you *did* send it somewhere, it may come back from there, because Git really likes to *add* commits and will spread them like a virus, given half an opportunity.  So it's often unwise to "rewind" or "remove" commits once you've given them out (with `git push`, usually).

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't yet committed the file, you can simply move the the new branch and carry on:

```sh
git switch -c branchA
```

If you have already committed the file, you can restore it to a certain commit before moving it to the new branch:

```sh
git restore -s <commit> myscript.py
git switch -c branchA
```

Comment: The file has already been committed on `main`. I just need to move it based on the most recent commit. If I run `git switch -c branchA` I get `fatal: A branch named 'branchA' already exists`. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh if branch `branchA` already exists, just omit the `-c`: `git switch branchA` and you should be all set